# Display entries by Category (Category in Super Table)

Tags: categories, category, plugin-supertable

I'm been kicking myself for hours and going round in circles trying to get list of entries displayed by category when the category is selected from within a SuperTable (static table) row. I would really appreciate if someone could please help point me in the right direction.

I have a structure entries section named "services" with a number of entries created.
I have a category group named "serviceCategories"
I have a "SuperTable" static table field handle named "service"
In my SuperTable I have a row named "serviceCategory" which allows me to select a single category from the category group named "serviceCategories".

I'd like to create a standalone web page that displays all the category titles with the list of related entries.

I've tried:

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('serviceCategories') %}
{% for category in categories %}

  {{ category.title }}

  {% set services = craft.entries.section('services').relatedTo(
    { targetElement: row.serviceCategory }
  ) %}

  {% for service in services %}
    {{ service.title }}
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but relation support has just been added to [Super Table 0.3.7](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable). Previously, relations wouldn't work with Super Table, as its a little bit of a special field, having sub-queries to perform for relations (each row).

You can now query fields just like Matrix:

```
{% set reverseRelatedElements = craft.supertable.getRelatedElements({
 relatedTo : {
   targetElement: entry,
   field: 'superTableFieldHandle.columnHandle'
 },
 elementType : 'Entry',
 criteria: {
   section: 'someSection'
 }
}) %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the targetElement option? Could you not just do:

```
{% set services = craft.entries.section('services').relatedTo(row.serviceCategory) %}
```

Also where is `row` coming from, because your not defining that anywhere?